# HTML vs. XHTML in timing of loading external style sheets

Tags: css, xhtml

This is a follow-up to [What is Google Search Console's complaint about CLS (cumulative layout shift)? - Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/129790/what-is-google-search-consoles-complaint-about-cls-cumulative-layout-shift).

I've narrowed the problem down to a very small example, and the only difference between working correctly and causing a redraw and layout shift seems to be whether an external style sheet is loaded by XHTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Title</title>

    /* Both define only the following one line of style. */
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <style> * { border-style: solid; } </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table> <tr> <td>Test</td> </tr> </table>
</body>

</html>
```

As an HTML file, everything works correctly.

As an XHTML file, using the `<style>` tag, everything works correctly.

But if I remove that one line of style and the same information is provided by an external style sheet, reloading the page usually produces a noticeable jump as the page is drawn first without and then with that change of border-style.

That is, as XHTML, it appears that the page is drawn *before* the external style sheet has been processed.

Interestingly the problem doesn't occur in Firefox, but it does occur in Chrome and Opera.
Google Search Console also notices and reports the rewrite.

And yes, I know the solution is "don't use XHTML", but I'm curious about whether this is an actual bug, or is acceptable behavior for XHTML page loading.